# Custom messages in xtext based language server

Tags: java, xtext, language-server-protocol

I am trying to extend my language server to handle custom commands from VS Code client. To debug, I am using `SocketLanguageServer`. I send a custom command from the client:

```js
client.sendRequest("custom/data", "foo").then(data => console.log(data));
```

Since the server is not aware of this command, as expected, I get

```bash
org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.RemoteEndpoint fallbackResponseError
SEVERE: Internal error: The json request 'custom/data' is unknown.
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The json request 'custom/data' is unknown.
    at org.eclipse.xtext.ide.server.LanguageServerImpl.request(LanguageServerImpl.java:1039)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.services.GenericEndpoint.request(GenericEndpoint.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.RemoteEndpoint.handleRequest(RemoteEndpoint.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.RemoteEndpoint.consume(RemoteEndpoint.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.validation.ReflectiveMessageValidator.consume(ReflectiveMessageValidator.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.json.StreamMessageProducer.handleMessage(StreamMessageProducer.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.json.StreamMessageProducer.listen(StreamMessageProducer.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.json.ConcurrentMessageProcessor.run(ConcurrentMessageProcessor.java:113)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Just by implementing `ILanguageServerExtension` (leaving it empty as below)

```java
@JsonSegment("custom")
public class MyLanguageServerExtension implements ILanguageServerExtension {

    @Override
    public void initialize(ILanguageServerAccess access) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }
}
```

and binding it in `MyIdeModule`

```java
public class MyIdeModule extends AbstractKinematicsIdeModule {

    public Class<? extends ILanguageServerExtension> bindILanguageServerExtension() {
        return MyLanguageServerExtension.class;
    }
}
```

I don't get the error anymore, but the client still complains of the promise not accepted

```
stack trace: Error: Internal error.
    at handleResponse (./node_modules/vscode-jsonrpc/lib/common/connection.js:477:48)
    at processMessageQueue (./node_modules/vscode-jsonrpc/lib/common/connection.js:292:17)
    at Immediate.<anonymous> (./node_modules/vscode-jsonrpc/lib/common/connection.js:276:13)
    at process.processImmediate (node:internal/timers:466:21)
    at process.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17)
/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/out-vscode/vs/workbench/api/node/file:/mnt/vss/_work/1/s/src/vs/workbench/api/node/extHostConsoleForwarder.ts:31
rejected promise not handled within 1 second: Error [ERR_STREAM_DESTROYED]: Cannot call write after a stream was destroyed
```

There aren't many examples out there on how to use `ILanguageServerExtension`, and the ones which are available (e.g. sprotty) are way too complex. What is the minimal steps to make `MyLanguageServerExtension` aware of these custom commands?

**Edit 1:** I implemented the following function in `MyLanguageServerExtension`, but same behaviour

```java
    @JsonNotification
    CompletableFuture <String>  data(String message) {
        System.out.println(message);
        CompletableFuture<String> completableFuture = new CompletableFuture<>();
        completableFuture.complete(message + " Hello from server!");
        return completableFuture;
    }
```

**Edit 2:** based on the code here: https://github.com/eclipse/xtext/blob/main/org.eclipse.xtext.ide/src/org/eclipse/xtext/ide/server/LanguageServerImpl.java#L1108-L1132 and the example here https://github.com/eclipse/xtext/blob/94c00e3ea5a6f952806a9e1a94b2325481e4eca4/org.eclipse.xtext.ide.tests/testlang-src/org/eclipse/xtext/ide/tests/testlanguage/ide/TestLangLSPExtension.java, I updated the code as follows

```java
@JsonSegment("custom")
public class MyLanguageServerExtension implements JsonRpcMethodProvider, ILanguageServerExtension {

    
    private ILanguageServerAccess access;


    @Override
    public void initialize(ILanguageServerAccess access) {
        this.access = access;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, JsonRpcMethod> supportedMethods() {
        // Define the supported methods and their corresponding JSON-RPC handlers here
        Map<String, JsonRpcMethod> methods = new HashMap<>();
        methods.putAll(ServiceEndpoints.getSupportedMethods(getClass()));
        return methods;
    }
    
    @JsonRequest
    CompletableFuture <String>  data(String message) {
        System.out.println(message);
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(message + " Hello from server!");
    }
}
```

But still the method doesn't get called. The `supportedMethods()` gets called though. This is the print of `methods`

```
{custom/data=JsonRpcMethod (request) {
    methodName: custom/data
    parameterTypes: [Ljava.lang.reflect.Type;@56a4479a
    returnType: class java.lang.String
}}
```

**Edit 3:** failure trace of the test shown below

```
java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type [unknown] not present
    at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy.generateException(TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy.java:47)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationInvocationHandler.invoke(AnnotationInvocationHandler.java:88)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy28.value(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.services.ServiceEndpoints.lambda$getSupportedMethods$0(ServiceEndpoints.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.services.AnnotationUtil.findRpcMethods(AnnotationUtil.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.services.AnnotationUtil.findRpcMethods(AnnotationUtil.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.services.ServiceEndpoints.getSupportedMethods(ServiceEndpoints.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.services.ServiceEndpoints.getSupportedMethods(ServiceEndpoints.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.ide.server.LanguageServerImpl.supportedMethods(LanguageServerImpl.java:1060)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.testing.AbstractLanguageServerTest.setup(AbstractLanguageServerTest.java:252)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:688)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptLifecycleMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:126)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptBeforeEachMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:76)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeMethodInExtensionContext(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:490)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$synthesizeBeforeEachMethodAdapter$19(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:475)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeEachMethods$2(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:167)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeMethodsOrCallbacksUntilExceptionOccurs$5(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:195)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeMethodsOrCallbacksUntilExceptionOccurs(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:195)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeEachMethods(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:164)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:127)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:65)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:91)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:756)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
    Suppressed: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.io.File.exists()" because "this.root" is null
        at org.eclipse.xtext.testing.AbstractLanguageServerTest.cleanup(AbstractLanguageServerTest.java:262)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:688)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptLifecycleMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:126)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptAfterEachMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:108)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeMethodInExtensionContext(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:490)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$synthesizeAfterEachMethodAdapter$20(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:480)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeAfterEachMethods$9(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:236)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeAllAfterMethodsOrCallbacks$12(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:269)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeAllAfterMethodsOrCallbacks$13(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:269)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeAllAfterMethodsOrCallbacks(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:268)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeAfterEachMethods(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:234)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:135)
        ... 47 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/TypeAdapterFactory
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:151)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:821)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:719)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:642)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:600)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:427)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:114)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:125)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseSig(AnnotationParser.java:440)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassValue(AnnotationParser.java:421)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(AnnotationParser.java:350)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation2(AnnotationParser.java:287)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:121)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:73)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Executable.declaredAnnotations(Executable.java:614)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Executable.declaredAnnotations(Executable.java:612)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Executable.getAnnotation(Executable.java:582)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.getAnnotation(Method.java:693)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.services.AnnotationUtil.createMethodInfo(AnnotationUtil.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.services.AnnotationUtil.findRpcMethods(AnnotationUtil.java:64)
    ... 78 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 104 more
```

Comment: Are you talking about the commands that are part of the [LSP protocol](https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol/specifications/lsp/3.17/specification/#command) or do you want to extend the LSP protocol itself?

Comment: I want to extend the protocol. Pass custom commands that are not part of the LSP.

Comment: I have seen some examples on how to write a server from scratch in nodejs and java, but not getting a simple enough example to extend an existing server impl.

Comment: Here the methods defined from ILanguageServerExtension gets added to the map: https://github.com/eclipse/xtext/blob/main/org.eclipse.xtext.ide/src/org/eclipse/xtext/ide/server/LanguageServerImpl.java#L1108-L1132

Comment: are you aware of the server module. this is the one contructing the LanguageServerImpl

Comment: I have added the code above where I bind MyLanguageServerExtension in MyIdeModule using bindILanguageServerExtension

Comment: @ChristianDietrich please check my edit 2

Comment: again Server Module = Server in general. Ide Module = Language Specific.
=> where did you bind your LanguageServer Subclass

Comment: I am using the existing SocketServerLauncher and LanguageServerImpl. I thought if you are using ILanguageServerExtension, you don't need to write your own LanguageServer. Maybe I have misunderstood the purpose of ILanguageServerExtension in that case

Comment: what do I need to implement in my LanguageServer subclass?

Comment: beside that it would be really helpful to have a reproducing sample and unit test.

Comment: you might also have a look at org.eclipse.xtext.ide.tests.testlanguage.ide.TestLangLSPExtension in Xtext codebase

Comment: if you want to subclass language server you need to create your own launcher class / servermodule subclass

Comment: @ChristianDietrich I have based my code on TestLangLSPExtension, and ideally I would not want to implement my own LanguageServer. I have used the existing SocketServerLauncher and LanguageServerImpl, and implemented  MyLanguageServerExtension, which I have shown above.

Comment: I am skeptical of what JSON message does `client.sendRequest` actually sends. Maybe that's the culprit -- will debug it and get back

Comment: maybe the problem is also the simple param.
to my knowledge all parameters in the protocol are wrapped into params objects

Answer (score 1):

i gave it a quick try with this test and it works fine

```
public class DullyTest extends AbstractLanguageServerTest {

    public DullyTest() {
        super("mydsl");
    }


    @Test
    public void testit() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        initialize( (e) -> {});

        MessageConsumer consumer = new MessageConsumer() {
            @Override
            public void consume(Message message) throws MessageIssueException, JsonRpcException {
                System.out.println(message);
            }
        };
        // languageServer.supportedMethods();
        RemoteEndpoint endpoint = new RemoteEndpoint(consumer , languageServer);
        endpoint.consume(init(new RequestMessage(), it -> {
            it.setId("1");
            it.setMethod("custom/data");
            it.setParams("myparam");
        }));
    }

    static <T> T init(T value, Consumer<T> initializer) {
        initializer.accept(value);
        return value;
    }

}
```

Comment: That's good news! So does that confirm that `client.sendRequest` is not written the right way? Here is how parameters are supposed to be created: https://www.jsonrpc.org/specification#parameter_structures

Comment: does the test work for you too? did you remote debug the server? what does extensionproviders contain? what does supportedMethods method see from your extension? does it go into any of the log error cases?

Comment: I have added the output of supportedMethods in the last part of "Edit 2"

Comment: I will try out the test and get back

Comment: could you please give me some details on how you ran the above test? I have added the failure trace above as edit 3

Comment: added missing dependencies like junit4 (the `@Test` is from junit4), lsp4j, lsp4j.jsonrpc, gson, aopalliance and co to the deps of the tests project. in the tests launch config select junit4